# Mongodb unwrap array

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I have a lot of documents like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "namespace" : "a",
    "version" : "1.1.1",
    "otherStuff" : ...
    (20 more...)
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "a",
    "namespace" : "a",
    "version" : "2.1.1",
    "otherStuff" : ...
    ...
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "b",
    "namespace" : "a",
    "version" : "1.1.1",
    "otherStuff" : ...
    ...
}
```

Now I want to aggregate this so that I only get the documents with the highest version number, grouped by (name, namespace). I came up with the following, however I want to use it in my java code and I just can't get it to work to unwrap the last step into the whole object like it is in the first step.

```
[
{$sort: {
  "version": 1
}},
{$group:  {
        "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
                "namespace": "$namespace"
              },
        "version": { "$last": "$version" },
        "object": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
}},
 {$sort: {
  "object.namespace": 1,
  "object.name":1
}},
 {$project: {
  object:1,
  _id:0
}}
]
```

But this gives me:

```
{ 
  object: [...], 
  object: [...]
}
```

What I am looking for is the representation like in my first example, I just want to select id 2 and 3.
I tried $unwrap but it seems I was using it wrong because it just yielded the same result as my $project stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `$replaceRoot` to make the object to be in Root as a last stage

```
{
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$object"
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nodWAjFUB2h)**